# Understanding the proof of an extension theorem

Tags: continuity, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

I'm studying the proof of the following theorem, but there are two things that I have not been able to understand about the continuity of the function $g$ on the boundary of $A$.

**(1)**  Why  $\inf_{y \in A}(f(y)d(x',y)) = \inf_{y\in C}(f(y)d(x',y))$?

**(2)** How do I deduce that $d(x',A) = d(x',C) = \inf_{y\in C}d(x',y)$ and how does this imply that $(f(x)-\varepsilon)d(x',A) \leq \inf_{y \in A}(f(y)d(x',y)) \le (f(x)+\varepsilon)d(x',A)$?

I appreciate any explanation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the first one, you have to combine the two previous equations, the lower bound on $\inf_{y \in D} (f(y)d(x',y))$ and the upper bound on $f(x)d(x',x)$.

Comment: @1Rock According to the above, I get that $$\inf_{y\in D}(f(y)d(x',y)) \geq \frac{3}{4}r$$ and $$\inf_{y\in C}(f(y)d(x',y)) \leq \frac{r}{2}$$ The only thing I've been able to conclude from this is $$\inf_{y\in C}(f(y)d(x',y)) \leq \inf_{y\in D}(f(y)d(x',y))$$ Can you give me more details please?

Comment: Have another look at the definition of $D$, and how $\inf_{y \in A}(f(y)d(x',y))$ compares to $\inf_{y \in C}(f(y)d(x',y))$ and $\inf_{y \in D}(f(y)d(x',y))$.

Comment: @1Rock I need to deduce that $$\inf_{y \in A}f(y)d(x',y) \leq \inf_{y \in C}f(y)d(x',y)$$ and $$\inf_{y \in A}f(y)d(x',y) \geq \inf_{y \in C}f(y)d(x',y)$$ But, from the above inequalities I only have $$\inf_{y \in C}f(y)d(x',y) \leq \inf_{y\in D}f(y)d(x',y )$$ I think I should compare $\inf_{y \in D}f(y)d(x',y)$ with $\inf_{y \in C}f(y)d(x',y)$. Is $\inf_{y \in D}f(y)d(x',y) = \inf_{y \in A\setminus A\cap B(x;r)}f(y)d(x', y) \leq \inf_{y \in C}f(y)d(x',y)$? I'm really not sure about this. Please, I need more details to do this as it's not very clear to me yet.

Comment: You can't just use the inequalities in the proof, you need to use additional inequalities that follow from the relationships between $C$, $D$ and $A$. You know $C \subset A$, so think about why that immediately means $\inf_{y \in C} g(y) \ge \inf_{y \in A} g(y)$ for every function $g$ (think about the definition of $\inf$, and draw a picture with $A=(-2,2)$, $C=(1,2)$ and $g(y):=y^2$). 

In the other direction, think about how the infimum over the union $\inf_{y \in C \cup D} (g(y))$ compares to $\inf_{y \in C}(g(y))$ and to $\inf_{y \in D}(g(y))$ (draw a picture again).

Comment: @1Rock Can you be more specific? I dont understand your other direction.

Comment: Did you try drawing the picture for the first direction? You should be able to draw a similar picture for the second direction.

Comment: @1Rock Yes, thank you very much. The graph of your example helped me to understand many things implicit in the problem. Now, I know that $C\subset A$ implies $\inf_{y \in A}f(y) \leq \inf_{y\in C}f(y)$, but I also know that $\underbrace{ d(x,y)}_{y\in C} \leq \underbrace{d(x,y)}_{y \in A}$. So how do I get that $\inf_{y\in A}(f(y)d(x,y)) \leq \inf_{y\in C}(f(y)d(x,y) )$? I could multiply both sides of the inequality by $d(x,y)$ with $y \in C$ and plug it into the infimum, but I don't know if this is correct and I don't get the required inequality. Please I need help here.

Comment: For fixed $x$, you can treat $f(y)d(x,y)$ as a single function $g(y):=f(y)d(x,y)$.

Comment: @1Rock Thank you very much for your contribution. To finish, I want to add one last question: as is already known and by drawing a function, according to your suggestion, I have been able to conclude that $\inf_{y \in D\cup C}h(y) \leq \inf_{y \in D}h(y)$ and also $\inf_{y \in D\cup C}h(y) \leq \inf_{y \in C}h(y)$. Since $D\cup C = A$, we get $\inf_{y \in A}h(y) \leq \inf_{y \in D}h(y)$ and $\inf_{y \in A} h(y) \leq \inf_{y \in C}h(y)$.

Comment: How do I combine these inequalities with the previous ones to conclude that $\inf_{y \in C}h(y) \leq \inf_{y \in A}h(y)$? Until this part I have not used the fact that $\inf_{y \in C}(f(y)d(x',y)) \leq \inf_{y \in D}(f(y)d(x', y))$ obtained above in the test. I'm really confused here because the inequality $\inf_{y \in A}h(y) \leq \inf_{y \in C}h(y)$ has already been obtained before.

Comment: Try drawing some pictures, and changing the sets $C,D$ and the function $g$, and see if you can get $\inf_{y \in A}(g(y))$ to be strictly less than $\min\{\inf_{y \in C} (g(y)),\inf_{y \in D}(g(y))\}$.

Comment: @1Rock Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have already achieved it!